# On the convolution of $f(x)=\sin x/x$ and $g(x)=1-|x|$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, convolution

I am having trouble with computing the convolution of $f(x)=\sin x/x$ and:

\begin{equation}
g(x)=\begin{cases} 1-|x|,& -1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0, & x \notin [-1,1] \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I have found until now that:

\begin{equation}
(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-y)g(y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x-y)f(y)dy=\\
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}dy+\int_{-1}^{0}y\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}dy+\int_{0}^{1}y\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}dy
\end{equation}

and for

\begin{equation}
I_1=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}dy 
\end{equation}

I can see that for $z=x-y$ I have:
\begin{equation}
I_1=\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\frac{\sin z}{z}dz=\frac{1}{2i}\hat{f}(-1)-\frac{1}{2i}\hat{f}(1)
\end{equation}

where, $f(z)=1/z$ and $\hat{f}(k)=-i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{sgn}(k)$ where I define the FT of $f$ as:
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx
\end{equation}

The problem is that I know that the Fourier transform of $f(x)=1/x$ is the one I mentioned above but for the integral limits to be equal to $\pm \infty$. How can I express the same FT but for the integral limits to be equal to $[x-1,x+1]$ as above so that I can use the $\hat{f}(\pm 1)$ of the FT of $f(x)=1/x$?

Also, how can I compute the rest of the integrals remaining at the convolution?

Thank you!

Comment: You can write $\int y\frac{\sin\left(x-y\right)}{x-y}\mathrm{d}y$ $=\int\left(x-(x-y)\right)\frac{\sin\left(x-y\right)}{x-y}\mathrm{d}y$ $=-\int\sin(x-y)\mathrm{d}y+x\int\frac{\sin\left(x-y\right)}{x-y}\mathrm{d}y.$ But I am not sure that you can find a "closed" form for the sine integral (i.e. an expression with usual functions).

Comment: @Nicolas thank you but what about the first part of the question? Anyone? Could it be so hard? I am sure that even if I cannot see it yet, it must not be so hard..